# Multithreading ThreadSeven extends Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have simple question from OCJP

Given:

```
1. public class TestSeven extends Thread {
2.     private static int x;
3.     public synchronized void doThings() {
4.         int current = x;
5.         current++;
6.         x = current;
7.     }
8.     public void run() {
9.         doThings();
10.    }
11. }
```

Which statement is true?

A. Compilation fails.

B. An exception is thrown at runtime.

C. Synchronizing the run() method would make the class thread-safe.

D. The data in variable "x" are protected from concurrent access problems.

E. Declaring the doThings() method as static would make the class thread-safe.

F. Wrapping the statements within doThings() in a synchronized(new Object()) { } block would make the class thread-safe.

Answer is option E.

My Question: as method doThings() is already synchornozed, doesn't it make thread safe?

Please also give some good links for these topics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `x` is a static variable, that is thus shared by all the threads. And since all the threads are not synchronized on a single object (every thread uses `this` as the lock), nothing prevents two threads to execute the `doThings()` method in parallel. Two threads might thus read the value of x in parallel, and then increment it in parallel, missing increments.

Making `doThings()` static would make all the threads synchonize on a single object: `TestSeven.class`

Answer (score 3):

A `synchronized` associated to an object's instance's method does not care of static variables, that are class's variables.
Indeed, in your case, the mutated variable is a `static` one: `x`

In order to synchronize a static variable, both easiest ways in this snippet code would be to declare `doThings()` as static (so that it would lock on the class itself, not the object), or to lock the `TestSeven.class` in the case of a `synchronized` block:

```
public synchronized static void doThings()
```

or

```
public void doThings(){
  synchronized(TestSeven.class){
    //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, That method `doThings()` is not thread safe, because, it was synchronized on `this` instance means different object will use **them** as the lock to access it. So no synchronization is there. If that method `doThings()` uses a shared lock to access the method, then, this method is perfectly synchronized. Or, making it class level property will synchronize.

Answer (score 1):

No, because it accesses the static field `x` non-atomically. You could also make it threadsafe by using an [java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement%28%29) with `getAndIncrement()`.

But the original form isn't, consider a second thread reaching line 1 while another thread is on line 3... one of the increments would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Though the answers are more on synchronized method of doThings(), which is correct, but in particular the static member x, “may be” cached with the values in respective Thread objects. The x will not be truely shared among all threads until it is volatile.